# Are internal string states analogues of internal particle states?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, string-theory, gauge-theory

It is sometimes said that in string theory elementary particles correspond to modes of vibration of a string.

Likewise in QFT, several particle fields take their values in a higher dimensional space, the basis elements of which, or otherwise some subrepresentations could be seen as distinct particles, e.g. the electron and the positron, and maybe even particles with different spin could be regarded as different particles.

Are these situations analogous? Can string theory be seen as a QFT in which there is a quantum field with an infinite dimensional internal structure space (rather than the 4D of a Dirac spinor), the basis element of which can be imagined as vibrational modes of a string? Or is that very far beside the mark?

Comment: "*several particle fields take their values in a higher dimensional space*" what is this supposed to mean? which higher-dimensional space? can you please elaborate?

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform A scalar particle has a single value at every point, but any other particle is a section of a higher dimensional bundle, e.g. a spinor is a section of the 4-dimensional spinor bundle, etc. Likewise (or alternatively) particles can take their values in a non-trivial representation of a gauge group (associated to a principal bundle).